# Should I edit questions where the title is needed to understand the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

I think it is annoying when reading the title of a question is required to understand the question. It should be a summary of the question and not a part of it. Maybe this could be included in "how to ask a good question" but my question is if you think this alone is a good enough reason to edit a question?

I am not clear enough about "how to ask a good question". I know it says a little bit about this issue, but I don't think it points out the importance of this enough. It points out the importance of a title that describes the question well, but not the importance of the question being understandable without the title.

But this is a side thing. My main question is still if I should edit questions where the only problem is that the title is needed to understand the question.

Comment: I also find this irritating.  I'd vote to edit in that case (assuming that it is otherwise a high-quality question).

Comment: Re: _"Maybe this could be included in "how to ask a good question""_: Have you read the [_"How do I ask a good question?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page? [The first directive is all about that, and most of the first "page" of content covers that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqkFH.png), so... it's already there.

Comment: What's funny is that while trying to understand your question the title is needed ;)

Comment: Googling site:stackoverflow.com "the question is in the title".  Four and a half thousand hits.  Keeps you busy for a while :)

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes I have. I clarified it now. Thanks.

Comment: @jontro You should have edited the question. :D

Comment: @jontro Sorry but I'm looking through the edit history and no version of this question actually needs the title. OP states in the description:"I think it's annoying when reading the title of a question is required to understand the question" and "Is this alone a good enough reason to edit a question?" These 2 sentences makes the title obsolete to understanding the question. These 2 sentences have been in the question since the beginning. Am I missing something?

Comment: Tell 'em what you're going to ask 'em; ask 'em; tell 'em what you asked 'em.

Comment: IMO, the only time I have a problem with a question title not matching the question body is when the two are so detached as to be two separate questions altogether, and I can't work out which one the asker is looking for an answer to, so I have to either divide my answer into two sections if I'm game on answering both, or close the question as unclear. I don't really have a problem if the title and body are sufficiently related albeit dependent on one another, because you *never* see the body without the title anyway. I also have more of a problem with altogether misleading titles.

Comment: I just accidentally flagged for "unclear what you ask for" because of this. At first I thought "ops", but the next second I felt "told ya". :)

Answer (score 12):

"Maybe this could be included in 'how to ask a good question'" is already implemented as pointed out by Tiny Giant's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357763/should-i-edit-questions-where-the-title-is-needed-to-understand-the-question#comment522196_357763): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

> In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title.

And as result editing is reasonable action: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

> to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it

Note that if it is the only "problem" with the post I'd keep it as is, especially if your edit needs to be reviewed. Fortunately most post have multiple issues and edit fixing all of them at once is always welcome.

Comment: To me, "expanding on the summary" does not imply restating the summary. For example, this sentence expands on my first sentence, but still depends on it to make sense.